# Firebase DB access && Security rules

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm developing an Android app that works with a Firebase database. The way is set up the app it does not require any kind of authentication and the users are only allowed to read from the DB.
I would like to find out a way to restrict access to DB only to people that are using my App.
I know that storing "default" credentials is not the best for safety purposes and I also tried with Anonymous Auth but I'm not sure that it is properly working (I tried to remove the auth-step and I can always access to the DB from my App).

Here the code which authenticates users:

```
private void getAuthentication() {

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuth.signInAnonymously().addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authenticated!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Firebase auth rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "false"
  }
}
```

I read a bunch of questions on the web but no one seems to help me :/

Any idea?

Comment: "I also tried with Anonymous Auth but I'm not sure that it is properly working".  Have you test it? Do you get an error?

Comment: Yes it works, the way I set the rules up it only allows authenticated users to read data, which is what is wanted. Just I'm wondering about the security of Anonymous Auth, still didn't find any explaination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules above will let only authenticated users to read data from your database. So, it doesn't matter if the users are anonymous authenticated (which can be converted later into normal users) or the users are authenticated with user and password or any other providers like Googe, Facebook, Twitter and so on, the same rules applies. This is the first and most important rule in order to use Firebase security rules, the users mush be authenticated.

Comment: Is there everything alright, can I help you with other informations?

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. But the problem is another: I'm using this type of authentication because I don't need any kind of login authentication from the user. Therefore I'm wondering about the security of the Anonymous Authentication, I mean, are just my App's users allowed to authenticate themselves within the app or it's possible that someone could authenticate himself from outside the app? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, your App's users will be allowed to authenticate themselves within the app. It's not possible that someone could authenticate himself from outside the app.

Comment: Might you show me any example in docs or whatever where it explains this "end-to-end" system authentication? I can't find anything in the documentation, I read a lot about but could 't find what you are saying :c

Comment: Why do you say that the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth) is not helping you? You can find there everything you should know about anonymous auth. But you should make your own attempt to create an "end-to-end" system authentication given the information in the docs, and ask another question if something else comes up.